# GWT Multipage App

Tags: gwt

I am confused about how to make a multipage app in one GWT project. I have one page with my app and would like to provide an options page.

I don't think you can use 2 onModuleLoads() or something.

So how can you achieve a multipage app in **1 module**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the MVP architecture -
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html

Even though you don't actually need an MVP paradigm to create a 'Multi-page' gwt application, you will be better off following it in creating your apps.

Basic idea is, you create different view-presenters that will act like different 'pages', and the app controller activates the correct one based on the logic you provide.

EDIT - you can even create multiple html-pages with their own onModuleLoad(), You should prefer that only if - there are logically 2 different applications or you are modifying an existing webpage and cant do without it. I believe you don't have those issues based on your question. Let me know if its otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the link. No they are not 2 different apps. This might work, gotta take some time to go over it. Basically for this app I have one page that will be the application and and aanother page that will be used for the settings. Is there a simple way to do this without the MVP?

Comment: I have found a decent solution. Deck Panel works well. Thanks

Comment: Good, but you should look at MVP if you want to make really complicated apps.