# create muliple HTML page in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am new in **GWT**. Is this possible to create multiple HTML pages in **GWT**? and if can create, than it is relevant to create page?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a moment to have a read of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask proper questions on Stack. Try to show what you've tried, or any research you've done. It helps people answer your questions better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple pages tutorial in Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061705/multiple-pages-tutorial-in-google-web-toolkit-gwt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find any html page in gwt, you will find two entries which is common to all html page of gwt.

That is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{modulename}/{modulename}.nocache.js"></script>

 <body>
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
 </body>
```

It loads `module.cache.js` into `iframe`.

So In short gwt work on one page only. it is single page application.

Refer: [how you can do multipage in gwt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858821/gwt-multipage-app)

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to have multiple page patterns for the same GWT application, you can create multiple pages, GWT won't prevent you from doing that (it doesn't even know it is called from different HTML pages).

So technically it is possible, now it is said, I won't recommend you doing that. You'd rather do different css files and swap between them. It will be easier to maintain your app.